# Access Facebook App Permission Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is many people talking about the ability to leave your app in dev mode and test this endpoint. Without requirement of having the "Page Public Content Access" approved. Well, after trying to test this inside the Graph Explorer tool - either I am slow, or that's complete trash information.

Has anyone has success with the permission inside the tool or ? if so, what am i messing here.

Authorized the application in the explorer and get this

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "BqoZbQ2W2nV"
  }
}
```

I've spent a few hours on this - really growing more grey hair over it.

My thinking, people are not understanding the printed text and just post on here, without really looking into it.

> While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review,
>   your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is
>   true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an
>   admin, developer, or tester role on the app. If you want the app to be
>   able to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this
>   feature for review. Once you set your app to live mode, it will not be
>   able to see any Page public content without this feature.

In which case, I've submitted the permission for review and 2 times have been denied. We don't want to build out a complete application without the permissions working. How would you do that anyways, how would you test something and show it working for the review guys - without it actually working.

The video which was submitted showed us trying to use explorer without success. That's really all I want to do - test it in explorer and see if we can achieve the results and than build it into our application.

A few people have mentioned to use manage_pages in order to test it, which actually doesn't work. This permission is allowing us to see PUBLIC CONTENT on a page and search for pages, groups, etc. With manage_pages you can not do that - how could that be the way to test it.

This is what I am trying to use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/pages/search?q=XXXX
```

Comment: You will need to grant `manage_pages` permission, then you should be able to test with a page that your app user is an admin of.

Comment: Oh! So, we can't see the un-admin stuff until we are live. What I am trying to do is see if we can pull the "active ads" and show them within our application to users. Is that possible.

Comment: Using that permission you can't access a search function. Which is the entire point of what I want to do ...

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/pages/search?q=XXXX

Comment: @Michael, This is exactly what I'm looking to solve, Did you get any breakthrough?